# How to call a function asynchronously in php

Tags: php, yii

I want to execute these functions when user click on button but I want to execute `$model->user->email ? $model->sendUserMail(): "";` that function asynchronously in background while other function will execute as click occur
Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['create_send'])) {
    if ($model->save()) {
        $model->order_id = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) + '' + $model->id;

        // send mail
        $model->sendMail();

        //send sms
        $messages = $model->sendSMSMessage($model);

        // create booking history
        $model->createBookingHistory($model , $messages);                     

        $model->user->email ? $model->sendUserMail(): "";

        if($model->booking_stage != 'inprogress'){
            $this->sendPushToSeller($model);
        }

        $model->update();

        $this->redirect(array('index', 'id' => $model->id));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, is the `$model->user->email ? $model->sendUserMail():` not bound by the click or am I misunderstanding something? - If it isn't, call it with a cronjob perhaps

Comment: **A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ml

Comment: Let me clear when user click i need to execute these all function except this specified function , I want to execute that function asynchronously (in background) and no it's not bound by the click

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like Async Tasks in Standard PHP. You could install pthreads or you have to work with some sort of a Queue.
With a Queue it would work like that:

- Create a Mail-Send-Job
- Push that Job into a Queue (for example a Database)
- A third party programm (for example a cronjob) has to poll the Queue and execute the Tasks (send the Mail) if there are some

Or like @Alan Machado said, use AJAX. So your page can load, and the Buttons sends an AJAX Request to the Server that sends the Mail.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged it yii, so perhaps consider a RESTful API extention, and research AJAX and CRUD. It depends on how far you want to take it. But I feel a RESTful API with yii is the best way to go when it comes to AJAX.